# Android Room with multiple db

Tags: sqlite, android-room

I am using room currently (migrate from ormlite). I use one db file at the beginning. But then we need to implement IM base on the database. Shall I use room with multiple db(one db per user), Or any other good way to Implement IM?
It puzzles me very much -- One db file but complex table structure or multiple db with simple table structure.

Comment: Then I choose the solution of multiple dbs with simple table structures

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Multiple database one project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187050/android-multiple-database-one-project)