# Android - Multiple database one project

Tags: android, android-room

I would like to ask if is possible to have multiple database under one project, with Room Persistence Library? Changing dynamic the selection of the database. 
Thanks

Comment: I know it's possible outside of Room. SQLiteOpenHepler takes a database name as a parameter

Comment: @KostasC please check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50015622/how-to-select-from-multiple-databases-in-android-roomhow-to-attach-databases) post

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is possible.
Let's assume you have two sets of entities and two sets of DAOs. You can obtain access to two databases by:

- creating two classes that extends RoomDatabase:

AppDatabase 1:

```
@Database(entities = {/*... the first set of entities ...*/}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase1 extends RoomDatabase {
    // the first set of DAOs
}
```

AppDatabase2:

```
@Database(entities = {/*... the second set of entities ...*/}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase2 extends RoomDatabase {
    // the second set of DAOs
}
```

- instantiating the two databases:

Note that you'll use two different file names.

```
AppDatabase db1 = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase1.class, "database1.db").build();

AppDatabase db2 = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase2.class, "database2.db").build();
```

In this case, you can use both databases, but you won't be able to create queries between them. If you need to attach the two databases, then you should take a look at the link @Anees provided

Comment: As per Android documentations `Each RoomDatabase instance is fairly expensive, and you rarely need access to multiple instances within a single process.` how can we make multiple database or table with single instance of database

Comment: @androidXP expensive what? Reduce performance, eat a lot of memory? Can u clarify?

Answer (score 9):

You can reuse the entities and DAO if databases have the same schema and dynamically switch between them (*helpful if you want to have a different database file for each user*).

**Entity class**

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    public String uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    public String lastName;
}
```

**DAO class**

```
@Dao
public interface UserDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    List<User> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid IN (:userIds)")
    List<User> loadAllByIds(int[] userIds);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name LIKE :first AND " +
           "last_name LIKE :last LIMIT 1")
    User findByName(String first, String last);

    @Insert
    void insertAll(User... users);

    @Delete
    void delete(User user);
}
```

**Database class**

```
@Database(entities = {User.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserDao userDao();
}
```

**DatabaseClient class**

```
public class DatabaseClient {

  private Context mCtx;
  private AppDatabase appDatabase;
  private static String databaseName;
  private static DatabaseClient mInstance;


  private DatabaseClient(Context mCtx, String dbName) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;

    if(databaseName == null || !databaseName.equalsIgnoreCase(dbName)) {
      databaseName = dbName;
    }
    appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(mCtx, AppDatabase.class, databaseName).build();
  }

  public String getDatabaseName() {
    return databaseName;
  }

  public static synchronized DatabaseClient getInstance(Context mCtx, String dbName) {
    if (mInstance == null || databaseName == null || !databaseName.equalsIgnoreCase(dbName)) {
      mInstance = new DatabaseClient(mCtx, dbName);
    }
    return mInstance;
  }

  public AppDatabase getAppDatabase() {
    return appDatabase;
  }
}
```

Now you can query based on a particular database by passing its name in the parameter in my case here let's say `myDb`

```
List<User> users = DatabaseClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), myDb).getAppDatabase().userDao().getAll()
```

Remember whenever you perform the first call with a database name, it creates the database file. If a new user arrives and calls to insert its info, it automatically creates a new database file and inserts the info data into it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. assume  User1 login into the app, I've created User1DB; User1 then logout from the app. User2 login into the app, I've created User2DB. Now if User2 logout from the app and User1 re-login into the app, then how can I access User1DB there ?

Comment: @SolaimanHossain Room auto-creates the database with the builder params, first time if it doesn't exist. After this, if you query anything on the DatabaseClient instance created with the same dbName it uses the existing database.

Comment: @Deˣ Can you please help me in writing the test case for the above solution? I am facing issues in the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just solved it with koin. I was creating an instant message app, and mutiple account login was required. After user1 logon my app,  the databse name with im_id could be got, then by inject, I created the database with the id. Then user1 one logout , I just unload the datasource module and jump to the login activity. User2 then login, I reload the datasource module and created database for user2 with his im_id. Code as follows:

```kotlin
val dataSourceModule = module{
    single {
        Room.databaseBuilder(androidApplication(), AppDataBase::class.java, get<GsSelectedAndImTokenPersistence>().gsImToken?.gsImId ?: "im_database" )
            .build()
    }

    single { get<AppDataBase>().gsInfoDao() }
    single { get<AppDataBase>().gsGameInfoDao() }

    single { get<AppDataBase>().gameClientDao() }

    single { SharedPreferencesDataSourceImpl(androidContext()) } binds (
            arrayOf(
                ImDeviceIdPersistence::class,
                GsSelectedAndImTokenPersistence::class
            ))

}
```

```kotlin
 fun unLoadDataSourceModule() {
        unloadKoinModules(dataSourceModule)
    }

    fun reLoadDataSourceModule() {
        loadKoinModules(dataSourceModule)
    }
```

The interesting is, even if
get().gsImToken?.gsImId
is null, it won't create the default database with name "im_database" by using koin inject.

And This is where I create the database by inject ,after I got the im_id from server

```kotlin
 viewModel.gsImToken.observe(provideLifecycleOwner(), {
            ELogger.d("database initial","init database===")
            // Incase of the datasource module is not loaded by now
            KoinInitializer.reLoadDataSourceModule()
            val gs: AppDataBase by inject()
            gs.gsGameInfoDao().run {
                viewModel.initDao(this)
            }
        })
```

And the logout place:

```kotlin
class SettingViewModel(
  ...,
  val db: AppDataBase
): ViewModel() {
   ...
   fun onLogout(){ 
     ...
       db.close()
       KoinInitializer.unLoadDataSourceModule()
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Create database dynamically with dynamic database name; Make sure only one database is open in our project; Re-open database whenever you want. LateInit database ,created when you got the database name wherever from local or remote.